# Verify methods are called in order

Tags: c#, nunit, moq, verify

I have the following method:

```
public async Task DeleteAmendment(int amendmentHeaderId, int userId)
{
    // Delete the corresponding version records.
    await _amendmentVersionService.DeleteForAmendmentAsync(amendmentHeaderId);

    // Delete the corresponding lifecycle records.
    await _amendmentLifecycleService.DeleteForAmendmentAsync(amendmentHeaderId);

    // Delete the amendment header record itself.
    await _amendmentHeaderService.DeleteAsync(amendmentHeaderId, userId);
}
```

I am trying to verify that the methods are called in order.

I have tried setting callbacks (see below)

```
AmendmentVersionService.Setup(x => x.DeleteForAmendmentAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Callback(() => ServiceCallbackList.Add("AmendmentVersionService"));

AmendmentLifecycleService.Setup(x => x.DeleteForAmendmentAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Callback(() => ServiceCallbackList.Add("AmendmentLifecycleService"));

AmendmentHeaderService.Setup(x => x.DeleteAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Callback(() => ServiceCallbackList.Add("AmendmentHeaderService"));
```

But the list only contains the string "AmendmentVersionService"

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would they not be called in order? if you using await in each of them execution will wait for each to finish before calling the next one

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the test where you call DeleteAmendment?

Comment: http://hastebin.com/mawisanani.avrasm

Comment: the order of execution is important, I want to make sure a test breaks if another developer switches the order around in the future

Comment: does it work if you have a void DeleteAmendment and no await ? (i.e.: _if you remove the asynchrony_)

Comment: I can't do that as all the methods called are Asynchronous and need to remain that way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the same goal, with a different concept would be to have 3 tests, one per call. It's a bit dirty, but as a fallback solution, it could get you out of the woods

for the first call:

- Setup call 2 to throw an exception of a custom type `TestException`.
- assert only call 1 was performed
- Expect the `TestException` to be thrown

for the second call:

- Setup call 3 to throw an exception of a custom type `TestException`.
- assert call 1 and 2 were performed
- Expect the `TestException` to be thrown

for the third call:

- Setup all calls to perform normally.
- assert call 1, 2 and 3 were performed

Answer (score 0):

You could use continuations (below) but really if you need to garuntee that these things happen in order then they should not be async operations. Typically you would want the async operations to be able to run at the same time;

```
public async Task DeleteAmendment(int amendmentHeaderId, int userId)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Delete the corresponding version records.
        await _amendmentVersionService.DeleteForAmendmentAsync(amendmentHeaderId);
     }).ContinueWith(_ => 
     {
        // Delete the corresponding lifecycle records.
        await _amendmentLifecycleService.DeleteForAmendmentAsync(amendmentHeaderId);
     }).ContinueWith(_ => 
    {
        // Delete the amendment header record itself.
        await _amendmentHeaderService.DeleteAsync(amendmentHeaderId, userId);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't really help him: he wants to make sure the continuations are performed in the right order, with unit tests, not in the implementation

Comment: It would remain the same then or use .Wait. Either way you are not truely running an async operation if the order matters but to test them and ensure they are called in order this is how you would have to do it because you cannot guarantee the order they will finish otherwise.

Comment: _ou are not truely running an async operation if the order matters_ I strongly disagree. asynchronous doesn't equate parallel. **but** it's not the point. He wants to have tests to _make sure_ nobody messed with the code and inverted the order in which the calls are made, regardless of whether it was done with an await or ConitnueWith.

Comment: I agree with that but you still can't know when an async operation will complete because one might take longer than the other so if the outcome of one matters while testing before testing the next one then you would have to control the order of completion.

Comment: True. you can't know for sure if the second call was made _after_ the first, or _as a result of the first having returned_

Comment: I have decided to make the whole thing synchronous now!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you will never be able to know if a method was performed as a result of the previous one finishing (awaited) or if you were lucky enough not to suffer from a race condition (call made without await, or no ContinueWith)

The only way you can actually test it for sure is by replacing the default TaskScheduler by an implementation of your own, which will *not* queue the subsequent task. If the subsequent task gets called, then your code is wrong. If not, that means that the task is really executed as a result of the previous one completing.

We have done this in [*Testeroids*](https://github.com/Testeroids/Testeroids), a test framework a friend and I built.

by doing so, your custom TaskScheduler can perform the tasks sequentially, in a single thread (to really highlight the timeline problems you could have) and record which tasks were scheduled and in which older.

It will require a lot of effort on your part if you want to be that thorough, but at least you get the idea.

In order to replace the defaukt TaskScheduler, you can get inspired by the work we did on Testeroids.

https://github.com/Testeroids/Testeroids/blob/c5f3f02e8078db649f804d94c37cdab3df89fed4/solution/src/app/Testeroids/TplTestPlatformHelper.cs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stephen Brickner ...

I made all my calls synchronous which made the callbacks in the Moq's work like a dream.

Thanks for all your help much appreciated!